# Найти элемент в dom с помощью js со сложной вложенностью

Tags: html, jquery, css

Имеется такая структура dom

```
<div class="controls">
     <div id="dynamicId">
         <div>
             <input id="customfield_12663" name="customfield_12663">
             <span class="add-on">ic</span>
         </div>
        <span class="alert-hide">need find</span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Необходимо найти элемент с классом `alert-hide`

Пытаюсь найти так:

```
$('#customfield_12663').parent('.controls').find('.alert-hide').hide();
```

Суть в том, что надо найти элемент с классом `alert-hide` в `div .controls`, в котором есть элемент с `id customfield_12663`.

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/dyvyr8fy/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

1: `$('#customfield_12663').closest('.controls').find('.alert-hide');`
2: `$('#customfield_12663').parent().next();`

Comment: спасибо большое! первый вариант подошел)